# How to retrieve data from the datastore on Android device, using Google App Engine with Cloud Endpoints?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-datastore, business-logic-layer

I am building an Android Application using Google App Engine with Cloud Endpoints. I carefully followed this tutorial (https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-addentities), thus I managed to successfully perform insert operation in the datastore. Furthermore, because  I am facing the fuzziness of the beginner with respect to everything, I received a really good advice(that helped me to organize the information in my head, and then my code) in the following manner(I have inserted also the explanations):

1. JPA entity (POJO with getters and setters and JPA annotations only)
   => I have this, is a class called Note (I have the corresponding setters and getters) (it's stored in the myapp-AppEngine (server side).
2. Data access layer: This is a class with methods to perform queries on
   your JPA POJO (using EntityManagerFactory).
   => I assume it's the automatically generated class after I did Note >> Google >> Generate Cloud Endpoint Class. The obtained class is one the has Create,Read,Update,Delete operations. (I assume this one is the data acces layer ? - correct me if I am wrong, please).
3. Business layer: This is a class where I should manipulate the data I
   receive, then pass the result to the data access layer.
   => This is where it's a little bit unclear, because I am not sure how I should proceed. I should consider Business Layer as an intermediate class, where I manipulate the data, so that I do not access the methods from the Data Access layer directly from the Client-side (Android-side) of my application?

Or, is there any other way I could retrieve data from my datastore? Even if, I consider really useful this way of organizing my code, clear, and somehow natural. If anyone could indicate me how I can do this, I'd really appreciate it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

@Cropcircles , you can refer the following docs and sample code provided by google :

1, [Sample code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-java) for design of app engine backend in java using google cloud endpoints

2, [Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android) and [sample code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-android) for consuming the endpoints, that is accessing data from datastore, in an android client

3, You can find the guidelines also for consuming endpoints in [IOS](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_ios) and [JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_js) clients. [Samplecode](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-ios) for IOS